# A maximum principle in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, maximum-principle, linear-pde, elliptic-operators

Let $\delta > 0$ and define
$$
H_\delta(x) = \prod_{j=1}^{N} \cosh(\delta x_j), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^N.
$$
By straightforward calculations we get $\Delta H_{\delta} (x) = \delta^2 H_\delta(x)$. So,
$$
\Delta H(x) + H(x) = (-\delta^2 + 1) H(x) \geq a_1H,
$$
where $a_1 < 1$ is fixed and $0 \leq \delta \leq \delta_0 := \frac{(1 - a_1)^{1/2}}{2}.$

A paper I'm reading says that, using the function $H$, is easy to prove:

> Theorem: Suppose that $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $u(x) \leq Ce^{\delta \sum_{i=1}^{N} |x_i|}$ on $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some constants $C > 0$ and $0 \leq \delta \leq \delta_0$ and
> $$
> -\Delta u + u \leq 0 \text{ in }\mathbb{R}^N.
> $$
> Then $u(x) \leq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

**My attempt:** Notice that $a_1 H(x) > 0, $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$, since $\cosh(t) \geq 1, $ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, letting $L u = -\Delta u + u,$ we get
$$
L(u) \leq 0 < a_1 H \leq L(H), \text{ in }\mathbb{R}^N.
$$
If we suppose that $u(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0$, we get $u(x) > 0$ for all  $x \in B_r(x_0)$ for some $r > 0$. At this point I dont't know what to do. Any help even with another kind of meaximum principle in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is welcome.